# Telegram API getHistort flood wait isssue

Tags: javascript, telegram

I'm building service of getting chat histroris with following features of getting users information with Telegram API (no bot). The following code works ok on 1 week/months filters, but when I need history for 3 months for example, Telegram API send this several times.

```
[Sleeping for 28s on flood wait (Caused by messages.GetHistory)]
```

I understand what it is, but cant figure out how to work around this with my code.

```
  async function getChat(chat, inputDate) {
    const newFullArray = [];
    let lastItemDate = Date.now();
    let offset = 0;
    let inputDateMS = setPeriod(inputDate);

    while (lastItemDate > inputDateMS) {
      const history = await client.invoke(
        new Api.messages.GetHistory({
          peer: chatId,
          offsetId: offset,
          limit: 20,
        })
      );
      const length = history.messages.length;

      if (length === 0) {
        break;
      }

      lastItemDate = history.messages[length - 1].date * 1000;
      offset = history.messages[length - 1].id;
      newFullArray.push(...history.messages);
    }
    const messagesUntilDate = newFullArray.filter(
      (message) => message.date <= inputDateMS
    );
    const usersWithMsgsList = generateList(messagesUntilDate);
    const chatUsersInfo = getSortedUsersInfo(usersWithMsgsList);

    return chatUsersInfo;
  }
```

I've tried to use setInterval, but it didnt make anything.
Any advice much appreciated!!

Comment: Introduce a [delay](https://github.com/sindresorhus/delay) after each iteration of the `while-loop` e.g.  await delay(2_000); // for a 2 seconds delay`